# How to implement a specific sort?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I need to implement a specific sorting mechanism within my project.

Context: The end user wishes to see some items first when available.

```
private List<string> SpecialSort(string[] all, string[] pref)
{
    //I want to return my total collection: sorted like specified in my prefered order.
    return all.ToList(); // But now in the correct order!
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestSpecialSort()
{
    //Arrange
    var myTotalColllection = new[] { "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "corge", "waldo", "thud" };
    var myPreferedOrder = new[] { "waldo", "absint", "foo", "baz" };

    //Act
    var result = SpecialSort(myTotalColllection, myPreferedOrder);

    //Assert
    var expectedResult = (new[] { "waldo", "foo", "baz", "bar", "qux", "corge", "thud" }).ToList();
    Assert.IsTrue(result.SequenceEqual(expectedResult));
}
```

I am unaware of the existence of this sorting functionality within the .NET framework, if it does exist please enlighten me.

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? It is a question about programming: implementing a sorting mechanism. I have encountered many situations where the requirements were as a 'nice to have' to show  items in a order specified by the user. The user specified ordering often not covering the entire collection or sometimes even items not available in the collection at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
var result = myTotalColllection
    .OrderBy(x => Array.IndexOf(myPreferedOrder, x)<0?int.MaxValue: Array.IndexOf(myPreferedOrder, x))
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `myPreferedOrder` backwards, moving each one found in `all` to be first.

```
private List<string> SpecialSort(string[] all, string[] pref)
{
    List<string> listed = all.ToList();
    foreach (string s in pref.Reverse())
        if (listed.Contains(s))
        {
            listed.Remove(s);
            listed.Insert(0, s);
        }
    return listed;
}
```